# Clear a specific query cache in Apollo GraphQL Client in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have a use case including three components and need to clear the graphQL cache for one particular query.
I already came across `client.resetStore();` - but this would clear all the cache which is not recommended.

I cannot use a `refetch` because the component where `graphQL` exists is not the parent of the component where I need the data to be refreshed.

Is there a way to pass the `apollo client` cache for one particular query ?